# constexpr Endian conversion in c++14

Tags: c++, c++14, converting

This is my take for constexpr big / little endian conversions.

The code supports only little and big endian; mixed endian such PDP is not supported.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>

namespace myendian_impl_{

    template<typename UINT>
    UINT byteswap(UINT const a);

    template<>
    constexpr uint16_t byteswap(uint16_t const a){
        constexpr uint8_t b[] = {
            8 * (2 - 1)
        };

        auto const x =
            (0x00ffULL & a) << b[0] |
            (0xff00ULL & a) >> b[0]
        ;

        return static_cast<uint16_t>(x);
    }

    template<>
    constexpr uint32_t byteswap(uint32_t const a){
        constexpr uint8_t b[] = {
            8 * (2 - 1),
            8 * (4 - 1)
        };

        auto const x =
            (0x000000ffULL & a) << b[1] |
            (0x0000ff00ULL & a) << b[0] |
            (0x00ff0000ULL & a) >> b[0] |
            (0xff000000ULL & a) >> b[1]
        ;

        return static_cast<uint32_t>(x);
    }

    template<>
    constexpr uint64_t byteswap(uint64_t const a){
        constexpr uint8_t b[] = {
            8 * (2 - 1),
            8 * (4 - 1),
            8 * (6 - 1),
            8 * (8 - 1)
        };

        auto const x =
            (0x00000000000000ffULL & a) << b[3] |
            (0x000000000000ff00ULL & a) << b[2] |
            (0x0000000000ff0000ULL & a) << b[1] |
            (0x00000000ff000000ULL & a) << b[0] |
            (0x000000ff00000000ULL & a) >> b[0] |
            (0x0000ff0000000000ULL & a) >> b[1] |
            (0x00ff000000000000ULL & a) >> b[2] |
            (0xff00000000000000ULL & a) >> b[3]
        ;

        return static_cast<uint64_t>(x);
    }

    // ==============================

    class isBE{
        constexpr static uint32_t u4 = 1;
        constexpr static uint8_t  u1  = (const uint8_t &) u4;
    public:
        constexpr static bool value = u1 == 0;
    };

    // ==============================

    template<bool b>
    struct be_tag{};

    // ==============================

    template<typename UINT>
    constexpr UINT htobe(UINT const a, be_tag<true>){
        return a;
    }

    template<typename UINT>
    constexpr UINT htobe(UINT const a, be_tag<false>){
        return byteswap(a);
    }

} // namespace myendian_impl_

constexpr inline uint16_t htobe16(uint16_t const a){
    using namespace  myendian_impl_;
    return htobe(a, be_tag<isBE::value>{});
}

constexpr inline uint32_t htobe32(uint32_t const a){
    using namespace  myendian_impl_;
    return htobe(a, be_tag<isBE::value>{});
}

constexpr inline uint64_t htobe64(uint64_t const a){
    using namespace  myendian_impl_;
    return htobe(a, be_tag<isBE::value>{});
}


int main(){
    printf("%16x %16x\n",   0x1122,         htobe16(0x1122)         );
    printf("%16x %16x\n",   0x11223344,     htobe32(0x11223344)     );
    printf("%16lx %16lx\n", 0x1122334455667788, htobe64(0x1122334455667788) );
}
```

Comment: Does this work on machines with [PDP-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Middle-endian) (`BACD`) hardware?

Comment: nope. I will add comment.

Comment: I've amended the description slightly to more clearly explain what the code is supposed to do.  Please make sure my edits are correct according to your intent.

Comment: something i'm doing locally is, instead of using `b[0]` `b[1]` `b[2]` `b[3]`, i'm using `0x08` `0x18` `0x28` `0x38`, which have the same values and preserve the byte offset numbers, but are much more concise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In all, this looks pretty solid to me, so I have only a few suggestions:

### Eliminate spurious `inline`

The `inline` keyword is only useful if this is moved to a header file, so it's not strictly needed in the context of the code in the question.

### Consider defining a string literal

Here's a small enhancement: provide the ability to define a string literal.  Here's how it might be done:

```
constexpr uint32_t operator"" _be32(unsigned long long num) {
    return htobe32(num);
}
```

Usage:

```
printf("%16x %16x\n",   0x11223344,     0x11223344_be32     );
```

This makes things very tidy and easy to use.  Naturally, 16- and 64-bit versions are almost identical except for return type and name.

Comment: "inline" is for header file.

Comment: Oh yes, of course!  I overlooked the obvious.  Fixed my answer.

Comment: Doesn't work. gcc 9.3.0 complains `error: call to non-‘constexpr’ function ‘__uint32_t __bswap_32(__uint32_t)’`

Comment: @ilya1725: There is no function `__bswap_32()` used here. Try using `constexpr htobe32()` as shown.  It works perfectly here using gcc 9.3.1.

Comment: @Edward I did that. The compiler came back with the error specified. What options do you use to compile? Mine is `-O2`

Comment: I use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2 endian.cpp -o endian`.  Again, though, this is not the problem.  Somehow you have introduced a call to `bswap_32` that *does not exist* in the posted code.  Try `-O0` to prove it to yourself.

Comment: See https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/2Y-grU to examine resulting assembly.

Comment: @Nick `constexpr` implies `inline`, so it isn't necessary anyway.

Comment: inline is for header file. not sure I can do without?

Comment: in my `/usr/include/endian.h`, `htobe32` is defined as a call to `bswap_32`.  The complaint makes total sense.

Answer (score 2):

### CORRECT Endian detection:

With the great help of Fabio A, I was able to check several codes that claim to work.

However some of them do not work and some works only in `gcc`.

Seems the only working way to detect endian-nes on compile time on both `gcc` and `clang` is as follows:

```
constexpr static auto check__(){
    #if defined(__BYTE_ORDER__) && __BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__

        return Endian::BIG;

    #elif   defined(__BYTE_ORDER__) && __BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__

        return Endian::LITTLE;

    #else

        return Endian::UNKNOWN;

    #endif
}
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1oMjjb

Comment: Sorry, but you are wrong in your statement that "It in a way do u4 to be accessed as array": what is really happening is that the compiler generates a temporary variable whose type is `uint8_t` and casts the `uint32_t` variable into it. Then a const reference to that temporary is taken, and its value is copied into the `u1` variable.

If your claim were true, the `static_assert()`'s would fail on a big endian machine, right? Well, they don't. See godbolt (ARM, big endian):  https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/K68Yn8

Comment: thank you very much. I knew ARM have big endian but I did not know I can access in compiler explorer.

Comment: @FabioA. https://github.com/nmmmnu/HM4/blob/master/include/myendian.h updated. Thanks.

Comment: godbolt is useless for compile-time checks as it apparently runs on a little-endian system. Most compile-time checks will produce le, use `<bit>`.

Answer (score 1):

The `isBE` check is wrong. What you're actually doing is a cast from `uint32_t` to `uint8_t`, which doesn't give you any info about whether the system uses big or little endian: in either case the result that ends up in `isBE::value` is 0.

The correct way of doing it would be to do a `reinterpret_cast`, alas that's prohibited with constexpr.

Unfortunately, a constexpr check of the system endianess doesn't seem to be currently possible.

Comment: this is old code, I can not be 100 percent certain, but code works in production. When I cast, dont forget there is reference sign &, so it should do the trick. However never tried it on big endian.

Comment: I will do answer showing why this works

Comment: @Nick, if you never tried this on big endian, how can you claim it works?

Comment: I did check on BE machine. and it DOES NOT work. This is why I posted "CORRECT Endian detection" answer.